# WhereEqualTo Error Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I had hoped it would be that simple, but I get the following exception when trying to run the query: com.parse.ParseException: equality needs a value instead of [value0, value1, ...]

How can I get my List of Data objects that have this condition?

```
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isfollowing"));
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What are you querying against? Did you not forget to register the class in app class

Comment: @Mohammed Adil objectid is pointer of class and u send this in string value so its not possible to pointer to match string. 
ParseObject ib = new ParseObject("ClassName");
      ib.setObjectId(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
        .getList("isfollowing").toString());
      // then
      query.whereEqualTo("objectId", ib);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`whereEqualTo`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), use [`whereContainedIn`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereContainedIn(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection)).

Comment: Maybe your list is `null` or empty. There must be another issue. This is the way you ask for objects with a field value that equals to an element of the `Collection`.

Comment: am querying a parse list to display data if the objectId contains certain values within the parse list

Comment: if i use the username column and put usernames in the list it works,but when i use objectid column and object in the list it doesnt

Comment: This is the way you do it. I do it all the time (also for `objectId`). There **must** be another issue... You would have to provide much more information. Maybe your `isfollowing` field stores a different type of data... At this point it's just guessing.